# bootbox.js alert modal - closing the bootstrap modal behind it

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

I have a `bootstrap modal` which I am using as a form to capture information that will be committed to a database.

I am currently implementing my Javascript field validtions on various inputs and drop downs. I wish to pop up a specific `bootbox.alert` with a message. Example:

```
    if ((dropDownValueOne === 'Please select') || (dropDownValueTwo === 'Please select')) {

    bootbox.alert("Warning: Please confirm that you have selected a drop down value for both drop down A and drop down B.");                                                

}
```

The above is working just fine when it comes to displaying the error when applicable. Unfortunately it dismisses the modal being used for capturing the information in the process, is there any way I could avoid this when presenting the error bootbox modal?

Answer (score 0):

Closing this I found my problem, had `data-dismiss="modal"` on my save button :(